# Explore internal storage in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to explore Android internal storage? I need this for debugging purposes to aid my development efforts.

Comment: What do you mean by internal storage? if you mean e.g. where your app is installed and such .. yes you can.

Answer (score 1):

You can on the emulator, or on an rooted device.  just

```
adb shell
```

with the device connected, and navigate from there.

Comment: I know it's passed a long time, but may I ask you if there is a way to download files from the "files" dir? My app produces a PDF and I would like to open it with my PC to check its correctness before building the ContentProvider to open it in Android.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by internal storage? If you mean e.g. where your app is installed and such .. yes you can on the emulator. On the device you can if you are root..

E.g. you app will be installed in /data/data/com.pacakgee/ and in there will be e.g. a database folder and other stuff depending on what your app does.